# How to select rows with same index to form a new DataFrame in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe like this, filename is the index:

```
filename a b c    
1        1 2 3    
1        1 3 4    
2        2 2 2    
2        3 2 5    
2        8 9 9    
3        4 8 6   
3        1 1 1
```

I want to divide this dataframe into three dataframes and then process them one by one in a loop. Each dataframe contains rows with same filename like this:

dataframe1:

```
filename a b c
1        1 2 3
1        1 3 4
```

dataframe2:

```
filename a b c
2        2 2 2
2        3 2 5
2        8 9 9
```

dataframe3:

```
filename a b c
3        4 8 6
3        1 1 1
```

Also, in my situation, I actually don't know how many sub dataframes I will get in advance, so I want the program figure this out too and then I can use a loop to process each sub dataframe.

How can I do this in python pandas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do this if you want to get number of groups

```
group = df.groupby('filename')
group.ngroups
```

and if you want to apply your custom function you can use apply where it takes your custom function as a parameter , and it passes each group to your custom function

```
group.apply()
```

you can try this simple function to understand what is your input to your custom functions

```
def print_group(df):
    print(df)
    print('-------------------')

group.apply(print_group)


   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  1  3  4
-------------------
   a  b  c
2  2  2  2
3  3  2  5
4  8  9  9
-------------------
   a  b  c
5  4  8  6
6  1  1  1
-------------------
```

Comment: Thanks, I just figured out by myself:

`pics = df.index.unique()`

    `for pic in pics:`

        `sub = df[df.index==pic]`

        `#process sub`